# Need Help with Update statement in SQl

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to sql database. I'm using the update statement to modify a value in my column. All my columns are of type char, but I'm not able to modify the column. Please point out what mistake I'm making

```
if ($info['Patient'] === '' )
{
    UPDATE guestbook SET Message = 'howdy' WHERE Name = 'mathilda';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook(Name)VALUES('$patient')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    //check if query successful
    if($result){
        echo "Successful";
        echo "<BR />";
    }
    else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
```

The rest of the code is working fine and the Insert statement is working good whereas I c an't get the update statement to modify the table.

Comment: Don't you see the difference between how your INSERT and UPDATE queries are performed?

Comment: I see a update query but it is not used or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you appear to be calling this from PHP you need to use the mysql_query method to execute the update statement like so:

```
$sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET Message = 'howdy' WHERE Name = 'mathilda'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
UPDATE guestbook SET Message = 'howdy' WHERE Name = 'mathilda';

$sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook(Name)VALUES('$patient')";
```

with

```
$sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET Message = 'howdy' WHERE Name = 'mathilda'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mysql_query()` for your update statement as well...

```
$update = "UPDATE guestbook SET Message = 'howdy' WHERE Name = 'mathilda'";
mysql_query($update);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = " UPDATE guestbook SET Message = 'howdy' WHERE Name = 'mathilda' ";
if(mysql_query($sql)){
   // true
}
```